# iOS UITableView.AutomaticDimension is not working

Tags: ios, swift, xamarin.ios

I have tried all the possible way.I used UITableView in that custom cells I have two label.I want to auto size that row if the text is more.It is not happening.Please help anyone know the answer.Please check the code and screenshot.

Note : This code is in Xamrin.iOS. You can answer in swift too

```
[Export("tableView:estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:")]
        public nfloat EstimatedHeight(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            return UITableView.AutomaticDimension;
        }
        [Export("tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:")]
        public nfloat GetHeightForRow(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            return UITableView.AutomaticDimension;
        }



public override void ViewWillAppear(bool animated)
        {
            base.ViewWillAppear(animated);
            notificationTableView.EstimatedRowHeight = 200;
            notificationTableView.RowHeight = UITableView.AutomaticDimension;

            notificationTableView.ReloadData();
            notificationTableView.LayoutIfNeeded();
        }
```

[image: Please click here for screen shot]

[image: Label1 constraint]

[image: Label2 constraint]

Comment: add all the label constraint w.r.t to the content view of the cell also 
write
 label.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
 and label.numberOfLines = 0

Comment: I have added  the same number of lines and line break mode.still it is not working

Comment: also check the constraint of the label which has to be relative to content view of the cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried assigning values to cell using getter and setter methods?

```
    public string DescriptionTxt
    {
        get { return labelCustomerDescription.Text; }
        set { labelCustomerDescription.Text = value; }
    }
```

You can also try layout if needed for the cell, after assigning the text to the cell.

```
cell.SetNeedsDisplay();
cell.LayoutIfNeeded();
```

Answer (score 0):

your top and bottom component must has top and bottom constraints.

like, you must need to provide bottom constraint to label,

and write,

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)-> CGFloat {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
 }
```

Comment: top and bottom constraints are there

Comment: for all the components?

Comment: return 140.0 and see what happening

Comment: Tableview cell height is not changing